# Why should we use temp variable in File.toPath() (jdk7)

Tags: java, singleton, volatile

This is the method toPath() of the File class (jdk7)

```
    private volatile transient Path filePath;

    public Path toPath() {
        Path result = filePath;
        if (result == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                result = filePath;
                if (result == null) {
                    result = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);
                    filePath = result;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am very interested why we use `result` variable as a buffer. Why can't we work with filePath itself. I have read that it's a performance issue, and we can have some better performance while using a buffer non-volatile variable.  But I fail to see how we can get this performance?

Can somebody clarify this for me, please?

Answer (score 1):

It's always faster to work with a non-volatile variable.

When you modify a volatile variable, all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory". which is slower than using the threads cache.

here is an interesting article: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

Comment: But as I understand here [Path result = filePath;] we make reading from volatile variable too. So we still need to read from volatile first. If I am write, what's the point?

Comment: where can we avoid overhead reading or writing, if we still must do some reading to instantiate result variable?

Comment: I mean that I understand that volatile with memory avoiding cache and this is resource-consuming. But from my point of view the actual number of straight memory reading/writing hasn't been changed

Comment: you only read the volatile variable once. and that's were you gain performance over always reading and writing the volatile variable

Comment: so, talking about this particular case, if there is a point to use that buffer variable. I assume not

Comment: yes. you're right. without the buffer you would have 4 accesses (2 reads in the ifs, one allocation and one for the return) with the buffer you have also 3 accesses (2 reads to the buffer and 1 allocation) which is not that much of a difference.

Comment: If `filePath` is non-`null` you have only one access instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is only called once it makes little difference. If it is called twice or more, you save one volatile read at every subsequent call. And although a volatile read can be as fast as a non volatile read on some architectures (typically x86), it can be significantly slower on others.